# How to get hierarchy children based on a parent id in a SQL table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using postgresql for laravel api. I have users table that contain data like below,

```
id    parent_id
2       
7     2 
3     2
14    3
5     3
6     3
17    3
4     3
```

I face difficulties to query the data, if I have parameters parent_id = 2, then the result data should be like this,

```
id

7
3
14
5
6
17
4
```

I had been tried this SQL code

```
WITH    q AS 
        (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    users
        WHERE   parent_id = 2
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  m.*
        FROM    users as m
        JOIN    q
        ON      m.parent_id = q.id
        )
SELECT  *
FROM    q
```

But it showed error

```
SQL Error [42P01]: ERROR: relation "q" does not exist¶  Detail: There is a WITH item named "q", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.¶  Hint: Use WITH RECURSIVE, or re-order the WITH items to remove forward references.¶  Position: 269
```

I don't know what's the problem is,
Can somebody help me to solve this problem?
Any help would be appreciate ! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like below

```
select id from users where parent_id=2
union 
select id from users
where parent_id in ( select id from table where parentid=2)
```